# How to control the order of the selected items

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-dropdown-tree-select

I am using [react-dropdown-tree-select](https://github.com/dowjones/react-dropdown-tree-select) component for my project.
How can I change the order of the selected items?
The default selected item order is the same as the data list order, I want to change the order as the user choosing item order: every newly selected item will be appended to the selected list.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please post code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to implement a middleware function inside **onChange** listener to rearrange the selected element and then update the state of data